# Get physical hard drive of encrypted partition

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, hard-drive, encryption

Wondering how I can see on which hard disk an encrypted partition is on. It wasn't installed by me(a past coworker), so looking to get some insight into it. I'm logged in as the user to which the partition belongs to, but cannot figure out on which hard disk it is mounted. Running:

```
df -H /home/user/
```

gives me back:

```
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/home/user/.Private    213G   14G  188G   7% /home/user
```

Then running:

```
lsblk
```

[image: lsblk Output]

My guess is it would be mounted where Ubuntu is installed (in this case sdb1), but am just a bit confused as to what is happening here. Not the most versed in Linux filesystems, so any insight is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the output of `lsblk` in your question, the only encrypted partition is `/dev/sdb5`, the swap partition. The root partition `/` is `/dev/sdb1`, as you are indicating in your question. It is not an encrypted partition, but there is 'encrypted home', the content of the user's home directory is encrypted, as seen from the output of `df -H /home/user/`

This is typical for systems with an encrypted private home directory.

So the drive is `/dev/sdb` with the size 232.9 Gibibyte (250 Gigabyte).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So even though the /home/user/.Private 'partition' is mounted on /home/user, it's still part of /dev/sdb. And If I understand the encrypted home concept, this all goes to the encrypted swap once the user logs off?

Comment: 1. `/home/user/.Private`  is a symbolic link to the hidden directory `.ecryptfs/crypt/.Private` (a directory, not a partition). It contains encrypted data; 2. The content of RAM goes to the swap partition if there is not enough RAM for all data, that should be stored in RAM. When hibernating, the whole content of RAM goes to the swap partition; 3. It is not enough to log off for the clear-text data to be removed. You must shut down or reboot.

Comment: For some reason I assumed doing `df` on where the symbolic link points will give me the same result. Instead, it gives me /dev/sdb1 as expected. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Search for *Disks* in the unity Unity Dash. You will see an icon of a hard disk with a wrench, execute it.

It will graphically display all drives and corresponding partitions. From here it should be intuitive to find which drive contains the encrypted partition.